# SQL IN operator, separate input values at commas

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

user inputs to `text_field_tag` e.g. a,b,c are seen as one `value1` i.e. `value1 = 'a,b,c'` in a SQL `IN` operator `(value1, value2, value3,...,)` instead of `value1='a'`, `value2='b'` and `value3='c'`.

I'm using sequel's `db.fetch` to write the SQL. Splits and Joins and their associated regexp formats don't seem to give the form `'a','b','c'`, i.e. separate values in a SQL `IN` Operator.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why can't you split the single value into an array when it's read from text field? And pass the result array to the query?

Comment: what you're saying doesn't give the exact form 'a','b','c' which is what the IN operator expects.

Comment: @Nothing use `where` and pass an array, Sequel handles the conversion for you: `dataset.where(value1: ['a', 'b', 'c'])`

Comment: No. This can't work. I mentioned IN operator. It has to work with an IN operator.

Comment: Sequel uses the `IN` operator for arrays

Comment: It seems like there is nothing that can be done in sequel to go get the following WYSIWYG input 'a','b','c' as input to text_field_tag to remain the same when being parsed by SQL query.

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some user input as a string:

```
user_input = 'a,b,c'
```

and a `posts` table with a `value1` column. You can get `posts` with values `a`, `b` or `c` with the following query:

```
values = user_input.split(',')
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

DB = Sequel.sqlite
#=> #<Sequel::SQLite::Database: {:adapter=>:sqlite}>

dataset = DB[:posts]
#=> #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `posts`">

dataset.where(:value1 => values).sql
#=> #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (`value1` IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))">
```